# Meaning of "１部２万"

Tags: numbers

> たかが感想文とはいえ、ほどほどにリアルな文体と内容が好評で、今では俺の量産する感想文は現在１部２万で取引されている。

speaker talking about his trivial job of writing feedback for literature aimed at elementary schoolers, how many is １部２万 exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 1部2万で means 1部につき2万円で or "for 20,000 yen per article". (Replace "yen" with an appropriate currency unit if this is not a story in Japan.) 部 is a counter for articles, documents, booklets, etc.

In general, this is a pattern to express "X per Y".

> - 1日1回　once a day
> - 1時間9本　9 trains per hour
> - 1人5分　5 minutes per person (e.g. a contestant)
> - 1枚15秒で　in 15 seconds per sheet