# Asking 'how much is the hotel for one night'

Tags: particle-が

I'm trying to ask "How much is the hotel for one night?"

After doing some reading online, I've come to two answers. But I'm not sure which one is correct.

```
このホテルは　いっぱく　いくら　ですか。
```

and

```
このホテルは　いっぱくが　いくら　ですか。
```

Is the が needed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That が is not needed. いっぱくいくら is an example of the ["X per Y" pattern](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60992/5010) which does not require が. You can also say:

- このホテルは いっぱく**で** いくら ですか？
  <sub>(で marks a ["condition"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55564/5010))</sub>
- このホテルは いっぱく**につき** いくら ですか？
  <sub>(～につき explicitly means "per ～")</sub>

Using が may be not be entirely wrong, but I feel it's less natural than the other options.